# Specifying negative power in scientific notation

Tags: sql, syntax, scientific-notation

In SQL `SELECT 1E9` results in `1000000000` (one billion), but how to write `0.000000001` (one billionth) in scientific notation? I've tried `SELECT 1E-9` but it results in `1E-9` printed to output (on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)).

Comment: What you tried is correct. Here's another one to try: `SELECT 1/1E9`, which will probably print the same as `SELECT 1E-9` (because it is mathematically the same). What you see - and what gets *printed* - is just a *translation of numeric data into something printable*.

Comment: @PeterB you're right. I've tried `SELECT 1E-6` after asking and it results in `0.000001` printed to console.